# Remove initial part of filename

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files that I would like to edit.

They look like

```
20190122-233715-886_tlog.354.2019012223043
```

The prefix is mainly just date and time stamps and processing ID.

I need it to be

`tlog.354.20190122230435`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although in this case you did already get an answer, note that Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regular expression with a capture group allows you to
rename in a single pipeline.

```
Get-ChildItem *_tlog.* | 
 Where-Object Name -match '^\d{8}-\d{6}-\d+_(tlog.*)$'|
   Rename-Item -NewNAme {$Matches[1]} -WhatIF
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

Sample run with aliases (in my German locale):

```
PS> gci *_tlog.*|? Name -match '^\d{8}-\d{6}-\d+_(tlog.*)$'|Ren -NewName {$Matches[1]} -WhatIF
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel 
"Element: A:\Test\20190122-233715-886_tlog.354.2019012223043 
    Ziel: A:\Test\tlog.354.2019012223043".
```

Comment: Completely off topic, but your English is spectacular. I would have never guessed that it was not your primary language.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks for the compliments, I wished my pronunciation would come close ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Replace function. 
For Example:

```
 "20190122-233715-886_tlog.354.2019012223043" -replace "^.*_",""
```

Will return

```
 tlog.354.2019012223043
```

So you can do something like:

```
 $file=Get-Item -Path "D:\temp\20190122-233715-886_tlog.354.2019012223043.txt"
 Rename-Item $file -NewName $($($file.Name) -replace "^.*_","")
```

And file will be renamed